# HttpClientModule in angular library

Tags: angular

I am making a small library, and I require `HttpClientModule` for loading some svg.

The library can be imported in any angular project as a whole Module, or single module.

All Module using `MyLibModule`
Or only the SVG module `MyLibIconModule`

`MyLibIconModule` require HTTP to load SVG

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyLibIconComponent],
  exports: [MyLibIconComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
})
export class MyLibIconModule{}
```

Issue is, when the project that use the library also use `HttpClientModule` in their `app.module` Angular trigger an error that only one HttpModule can be imported because of the interceptor.

How could I meake this work ? Should I use forRoot for both  `MyLibIconModule` and `MyLibModule`?

`LibModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyLibIconComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyLibIconComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [],
})
export class MyLibModule{}
```

`MyLibIconComponent`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [IconComponent],
  exports: [IconComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule,/* HttpClientModule */],
})
export class MyLibIconComponent{}
```

(I needed to remove the `HttpClientModule` for the error to not appear)

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ui-lib",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "subsink": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

now In my project I currently import `HttpClientModule` in the app module :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MyLibIconComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but if I don't import `HttpClientModule` (cause like if the app dont need to use httpModule) the icon wont works. I want to make `HttpClientModule` a requirement when importing `MyLibIconComponent`

Comment: did you try to put dependencies  in peerdependencies(in package.json) in you LibModule?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to externnalize your own library in a form of a small angular project with its own dependencies and import it in your main project. This will ensure the separation of dependencies.
The Angular documentation have a complete [guide](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) on creating your library.
This is one of the solutions I can recommend.

Hope it can help.

Comment: this is what I am currently doing. I have a project library that is separated and with is own dependencies

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Updated to show that you need not import HttpClientModule in the AppModule to use it in your library module.

Cannot say for sure without seeing `MyLibModule`, but I am guessing you may be exporting `HttpClientModule` in `MyLibModule.` You should be able to use the `HttpClientModule` in your library modules without exporting `HttpClientModule` in that module. This will allow the `AppModule` to import `HttpClientModule` without interference.

This worked for me (showing an example with an interceptor in the library since you mentioned it):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyLibComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MyLibComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyLibInterceptor, multi: true}
  ]
})
export class MyLibModule { }

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyLibModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: this is actually true, but how to force the implementor to add `HttpClientModule`, or add it if there is no instance already created ?

Comment: Your library will still work even if they do not add the HttpClientModule in their AppModule, as long as you have @angular/common as a peerDependency in the package.json for your library. Your library will be able to use the HttpClientModule, and the app can add it if they need it, but as a consumer of your library, they will only need to add your library module to use your library.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Try this:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [IconComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
})
export class MyLibIconModule{}
```

you can delete MyLibIconComponent and MyLibModule, if your are using this modules only for this component, they are irrelevant.

You can use public.api.ts to export your module/component.

```js
/*
 * Public API Surface of lib
 */

// MAIN
export * from './lib/my-lib-icon.module'
export * from './lib/icon.component'
```

Comment: yes, I have all angular dependencies added, the problem is requiring user to use `HttpClientModule` and add it if there is no instance provided.

Comment: can you show us the LibModule/LibIconModule and the lib package.json? it's dificult to find a solution without this.

Comment: I edited the main questin @mpalliser

Answer (score 0):

Angular documentation provides a guide about where to put @angular/* dependencies while creating libraries. They should be put under peerDependencies [see this](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#peer-dependencies)

Your library's package.json should look like below:

```
  {
    "name": "my-angular-lib",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Devesh",
    "license": "MIT",
    /* Other details */
    "peerDependencies": {
      "@angular/common": ">=6.0.0 <7.0.0",
      "@angular/common/http": ">=6.0.0 <7.0.0"
      /* Other peer dependencies*/
    }
  }
```

You can see an issue regarding the same [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43058).